# Problem with layout of control when dynamically creating winform and controls for the Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I get this response from a web service call. Something like this

```
<Response>
<Control1 type = "DropdownList" value= "USA,UK,Sweden,UAE"/>
<Control2 type = "Textbox" value= "Contries"/>
<Control3 type = "Button" value= "None">
</Response>
```

Based on this I de-serialize it into `List<Controls>`.

Now I need to be able to dynamically create a winform based on these controls. **My problem is the layout.** I want to be able to create them nicely separated (If possible vertically aligned) in batches of lets say 5.So If I need 15 controls I have 3 columns and 5 rows. 
What would be best way to achieve this? I know that I can use the inbuilt positioning properties like top, width etc., but maybe someone out there has done something similar in a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use [TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx). Also you can read [best practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171689.aspx) to use this control.

One benefit of using TableLayoutPanel from above article:

> Layouts that will be modified or generated dynamically at run time, such as data entry forms that have user-customizable fields added or subtracted based on preferences.

Comment: Yes I think TableLayoutPanel or FlowLayoutPanel will do. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 0):

So basically I am gonna do something like this(might be useful for someone else)

```
Form op = new Form();
            FlowLayoutPanel panel = new FlowLayoutPanel();
            op.Controls.Add(panel);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Button b = new Button();
                b.Text = "Button" + i.ToString();
                panel.Controls.Add(b);

            }
```